# Text align in paragraph tag varies by browser

Tags: html, css

I am working on a redesign of my website and I've run into a strange problem. I have a simple paragraph that is `align: center`. It's displaying perfectly in Chrome, but the text is shifted to the right in Firefox and IE.

I have all paragraph tags set to `margin: 0px` as a baseline. I noticed that when I remove this, Firefox adds its standard 1em margin to top and bottom **and the text becomes centered**. However, I need the margins at zero for my layout.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div id="headline">
<p>It’s <span>easy</span> to get a great website, when you know how.</p>
<div>
```

Here is the relevant CSS:

```
p {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

#stage #headline p {
  font: bold 3em/1.2em Montserrat,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
  padding: .2em 6%;
}

#stage #headline p {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Add `clear:both;` to the `#stage #headline p` statement (either one).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an element in your header content that is pushing down into the area to the left of your paragraph.

Add `clear:both;` to the `#stage #headline p` statement (either one) to resolve the issue, visually.

Comment: Thanks! - see another note below about using :after{}, in case that's a better fix if Chrome is already playing nicely.

Answer (score 0):

Inside `#smallMenu > .small-inner` there are uncleared floating elements. They push the text in the paragraph to the right.

You can use

```css
#smallMenu > .small-inner {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: As an alternative, you could use `:after{content:"";height:0;clear:both;}` ?